# How to do sets in bash 3?

Tags: bash, set

Is it possible to do sets (with puts and gets) in bash 3? If not supported by the language (my searching got nothing), is there a common way of doing a work-around? I would have max number of items in the low hundreds.

I'm building up two sets and then wanting the difference between them (all items in set A but not B, I'm not interested in the reverse). The sets themselves are a list of dependencies/directories.

Comment: The closest thing are associative arrays, but those require Bash 4.0 or newer. I'd look into awk, Perl or Python.

Comment: @I'm firmly stuck with bash 3. :(

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You could do something with a normal array, but every check for presence of an element would be O(log(N)) if you implement binary search.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Updated my quesiton, thanks!

Comment: @Bren Could you give an example of usage, i.e. where you would call the script from (from within a script or the command line ?), and what different functions you want it to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround using common utils, supposing set *A* is *{1,2,3}* and set *B* is *{2,3,4}*, and output should be the unique items in set *A* only:

```
diff -y <(seq 3) <(seq 2 1 4) | grep '<' | cut -f1
```

Output:

```
1
```

If [`combine`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is available, the same can be done like so:

```
combine <(seq 3) not <(seq 2 1 4)
```